# Why does my subscription have the ID "timeline"?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

When testing out my [mirror-api gem](https://github.com/ciberch/mirror-api) I noticed that on a subscriptions:list call the id of my subscription ID "timeline". Is this a bug or the desired behavior? I thought it was off because subscriptions:get takes ID as the parameter.

```
{
   "kind":"mirror#subscriptionsList",
   "items":[
      {
         "kind":"mirror#subscription",
         "id":"timeline",
         "updated":"2013-04-21T15:21:31.385Z",
         "collection":"timeline",
         "operation":[
            "UPDATE"
         ],
         "callbackUrl":"myapp.com/notification",
         "verifyToken":"a_very_important_token_obvi",
         "userToken":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So I did a few tests against the API explorer and it seems that for each user you can only have a maximum of two subscriptions, one for "timeline" and one for "locations", which will also get these respective IDs.

When you already have a "timeline" subscription, trying to insert another one will overwrite the existing one. So for example you can't have one callbackUrl for timeline inserts and another one for timeline deletes (which is fine I guess since you can always split up the requests accordingly in your callback).

With just two subscriptions possible, having only the two matching IDs isn't really a problem. And actually makes things easier (if you can rely on this behaviour since it's not really documented) because if you need to update or delete a subscription you don't need to remember (or find via subscriptions.list) a random ID to use in subscriptions.update or subscriptions.delete

They actually make use of this behaviour in the samples for [subscriptions.update](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/update#examples) and [subscriptions.delete](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/delete) using the collection as id:

```
service.subscriptions().update(id=collection, body=subscription).execute()

service.subscriptions().delete(collection).execute()
```

I guess this is implemented in this way to prevent you from accidentally having multiple subscriptions for the same thing for the same user, but if this indeed the desired behaviour it should be included in the documentation.